# Wordpress issue - could not get domain name

Tags: wordpress, apache, test-kitchen

I'm trying to test a Wordpress configuration I'm building in Chef with Test Kitchen. The server is coming up with a temporary ip - this seems to have something to do with the error I'm getting when I try to visit the site in a browser:

```
Could not get domain name.10.10.0.1
```

No errors in the httpd error.log. Any ideas on how to get past this? I tried faking the hostname in /etc/hosts for the main ip but that did not work.

Comment: go to wp-config.php and enable define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );  mode. it will show you exact problem.

Comment: I enabled and restarted the httpd and mysql services - i see no errors in the errors.log or on the webpage.

Comment: did your domain name server (DNS) records correctly mapping with your hosting?

Comment: This is a temporary VM deployed on my laptop using Chef so it has no DNS entry. That is why I tried adding the hostname to /etc/hosts